# 12V or 220V for energy efficiency?

Tags: voltage

I just saw a DIY solar panel setup, in which a single panel produces 12V output, which is then passed through a controller and stored in a 72Ah 12V car battery.

The stored electricity is mostly supposed to be used for night lighting of the outside, and currently consists of a single 12V 3W LED lamp (and of course the associated night-time detector.)

The question is, is there any sense  (from energy efficiency perspective) to use an inverter and 220V lamps and other loads, if the required items can be had in 12V versions?

I would assume 220V loads would be more energy expensive to run, as the voltage converter adds another step in energy conversion and every step results in some energy loss. However, as I understand, high voltage lines are a better way to transfer electricity across larger  distances. The distances involved here are hardly likely to exceed 10-12m though.

Comment: At 5m and about 500W, my answer was to look for a deal on auto jump leads.  For low power like 3W, don't bother. For higher powers, 24VDC is a good compromise, halving the current saves 75% of the wasted power.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your hunch is correct. Voltage conversion, particularly from DC to AC, will cost due to conversion losses.

You are also correct that higher voltage reduces transmission losses. You can compensate for this at low voltages by reducing cable resistance by increasing the cable cross-sectional area.

There are many online calculators for this.

[image]

*Figure 1. [jCalc](https://www.jcalc.net/voltage-drop-calculator-as3008) (picked at random) seems quite comprehensive.*

Answer (score 2):

It is called *I^2 R* losses. If your load is small - in your case, 3w LED which is drawing *I = P/V* which is 3/12 = 0.25Amps. you should go ahead without inverter since your load is also DC. I^2.R loses in your case is negligible.

Converting DC to AC is expensive both in terms of efficiency and cost. The best inverters which are highly efficient 90-95% are way too expensive for smaller applications and then again you have to convert it back to DC - another step loss.